# Oracle Newbie Question - How can one run selects from different tables but show output on separate rows

Tags: oracle

E.g. Table 1 Japan Customers

Table 2 USA Sales People

Table 3 HK Engineers

There are selects from the 3 tables each. However, can I run all 3 selects within a single/overall select statement and output 1 result set, so one can see
each row labeled based on the table name? all these tables don't have similar columns but share a common id column

Col1        Col2       Col3...

Japan

USA

HK

Comment: You can merge the result of two or more different queries using UNION ALL, but number of columns and names must match.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible to merge/add the result of two or more different queries using:

```
UNION ALL
```

But count and names of columns must match on each query.

Of course you can add null or fixed values as needed.

```
SELECT COL1 AS ID, COL2 AS NAME, NULL AS INFO
FROM   TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT F1 AS ID, F2 AS NAME, INFO
FROM.  TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS ID, NAME, INFO
FROM   TABLE3
```